# Hang when try to install Visual Studio 2013 Express on Windows 8.1 (x64)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

Today trying to install RTM version of Visual Studio 2013 Express (Web/Desktop etc.) 
I receive Windows Application Hangup message window: "Visual Studio 2013 Express stop working...". In Event Viewer this message logged like:

Faulting application name: wdexpress_full.exe.
   Error (Application Error) Category 100. 
   Exception code 0xc0000005.
   ...

And this error was occurs when I trying install other Express editions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was unexpectedly simple: Just right-click on "wdexpress_full.exe", and select option for running application with other GPU! There is because my laptop use Nvidia Optimus - two GPUs...

Comment: Sounds like a bug, might be worth reporting on connect